# Out of universe, have any actions by Harvey Dent ever been determined by tossing a coin?

Tags: batman, behind-the-scenes, dc

Are there interviews where any Batman writer (Comic, TV *or* Film) has admitted to tossing a coin to decide what Harvey Dent was going to do next?

I'll accept rolling a die (or any other method) as long as it's random.

Comment: I'm tempted to ask the related question, "In all media, how many times has Batman foiled Harvey Dent by throwing his loose change in the air?"

Comment: I'm not aware of any, although any interview regarding the Adam West Batman show can already be ignored, as the only Batman '66 material Two-Face appeared in was Batman vs. Two-Face.

Comment: Also, do actors count?